# Check if mapped network available

Tags: vba, vb6

I am trying to have my program check is a mapped network drive is actually connected, and change the curDrive variable based on the result. It works okay, but if the drive is still mapped and the drive is not available, there is a long delay while the program tries to connect (4-6 seconds). I tried two methods and both ways have this delay. I tried the following:

```
    On Error GoTo switch
    checker= Dir("F:\")
    If checker= "" Then GoTo switch
         curDrive = "F:\"
    GoTo skip
switch:
    curDrive = "C:\"
skip:
 ........
```

I also tried:

```
Dim FSO As Object '//FileSystemObject
Dim f As Object '//File Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

With FSO
    If .FolderExists("F:\Sample") Then
        curDrive = "F:\"
    Else
        curDrive = "C:\"
    End If
End With
```

Both have the same delay.

Comment: Most VBA hosts do not have an async Timer control, which you'd need to use to monitor for completion on a worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching and brainstorming, I put together some info from here and from elsewhere and came up with a method that takes half a second. Basically, I'm pinging the server and reading the results from a text file. I'm also checking to make sure that the F: Drive (the server drive) is available (Someone can be on the server but hasn't set the F: Drive to the server).

```
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hHandle As Long,   ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwDesiredAccessas As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcId As Long) As Long

Sub CheckAllConnections()
    ServerOn = ComputerIsOnline("server.mmc.local")
    FDrive = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").driveexists("F")
    test = FDrive - 1
    ProgramFolder = False
    If ServerOn + FDrive = -2 Then
        ProgramFolder = Len(Dir("F:\SampleProgram\")) > 0
    End If
    MsgBox ("Server connection is " & ServerOn & "." & Chr(10) & "F: Drive available is " & FDrive _
    & Chr(10) & "The Program Folder availability is " & ProgramFolder)
End Sub

Public Function ComputerIsOnline(ByVal strComputerName As String) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\Logger.txt"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ShellX = Shell("cmd.exe /c ping -n 1 " & strComputerName & " > c:\logger.txt", vbHide)
    lPid = ShellX
    lHnd = OpenProcess(&H100000, 0, lPid)
    If lHnd <> 0 Then
        lRet = WaitForSingleObject(lHnd, &HFFFF)
        CloseHandle (lHnd)
    End If
        FileNum = FreeFile
        Open "c:\logger.txt" For Input As #FileNum
        strResult = Input(LOF(1), 1)
        Close #FileNum
        ComputerIsOnline = (InStr(strResult, "Lost = 0") > 0)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    ComputerIsOnline = False
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Both show the same delay because both methods invoke the same underlying OS functionality to check for the presence of the network drive.

The OS is giving the external resource time to be available.  I don't think you can do anything except await the timeout, if you want to know for sure.

If you know that, in your environment the OS timeout is just too long (e.g. "If it has not responded after 1 second, it will not respond), you could use a mechanism such as a timer to avoid waiting the full duration (set a 1 second timer when you start checking, if the timer fires and you still have no reply, the drive was not present).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the method to use timers. I never had the need to use one.

Comment: Assuming I check the value of curDrive when the timer fires, is there a way I can then stop the OS (program)  from waiting for the network to respond

Comment: @AbeGold: You would run the code in your post in a separate thread.  You could not stop the OS call, but your application could continue once the timer fires.  You would have the main thread of your app wait until one of two conditions is true: The separate thread to check the drive status completes, or the timer fires.

Comment: The Timer won't fire until after the full timeout anyway, since you are hanging your UI thread on a synchronous call.  So just using a Timer won't help you.

Comment: Yes it can.  You have a few options: ActiveX EXE, 3rd party Apartment Threading helper library, or very VERY careful use of CreateThread (not recommended for most people).  But even so you cannot "cancel" this long synchronous request.

Comment: Thank you.  While I cannot cancel the request,  I can have the second thread be busy with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no long delay when testing for a drive letter using the FileSystemObject and `DriveExists`:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim n As Integer

    For n = 1 To 26
        Debug.Print Chr(64 + n), HaveDrive(Chr(64 + n))
    Next n

End Sub



Function HaveDrive(driveletter)
    HaveDrive = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").driveexists(driveletter)
End Function
```

Comment: That is true. However I just ran a test. I have a mapped F: drive now, but it is not available. I ran Tester = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").driveexists("F")
and Tester returned True, so it will not work.

Comment: Looked at `IsReady` ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x681abd9(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Just tried the code from that link and had the same 6 second delay before getting a response.

Comment: All the same fundamental underlying issue that the OS gives the drive time to become available once it is accessed.