# Halt execution of VBA network connection test using Dir() if it takes too long

Tags: vba, performance, networking, directory, connection

I run an access database with a VBA form that connects to another access database on a network if the network is available. If the network is not available, it connects to a local `C:` drive to access database instead.

It works, however the network connection test I run (illustrated below with a fake IP Address) to see if the network is available takes too long when the network is not available (approximately 50 seconds).

```
Function OnNetwork()
    OnNetwork = False
On Error GoTo EndFunction
    If Dir("\\101.10.000.1\reports\_DoNotDeleteThisFile.txt") = _
        "_DoNotDeleteThisFile.txt" Then
        OnNetwork = True
    End If
EndFunction:
End Function
```

I have also tried the following, which also takes approximately 40 seconds the first few times - after that it is instant. The delays only occur when the network is not available.

Is there another way to get a result instantly every time?

```
Function OnNetworkNew()
OnNetworkNew = False
    On Error GoTo EndFunction
        Dim NetworkPath As String
        NetworkPath = "\\101.10.000.1\reports\_DoNotDeleteThisFile.txt"
        Open NetworkPath For Output As #1
        Close #1
    OnNetworkNew = True
EndFunction:
End Function
```

Comment: The solution has more to do with Windows than VBA code, I think. Something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/453741) maybe, but note that these settings will affect Windows as a whole, not just how long `Dir` times out after.

Comment: Have you tried using a FileSystemObject instead?

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562491/check-if-mapped-network-available