# vba to check create mapped drive or skip if exists

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a section in an `excel 2016 vba` that will create a mapped drive if it doesn't exist. If it does exist already then it just goes to the next section. The below is code so far. Thank you :).

VBA

```
# code
...
...

# create drive or skip if exists
Dim WshNetwork As String
On Error GoTo 0:
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\server\drive"
0:
Close

# more code
...
...
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Why not define `WshNetwork` as Object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562491/check-if-mapped-network-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`On Error Goto 0` is special in that it turns off error handling. The fact that you included a colon after it like it was a label just means you were putting two statement on one line. The first turning off error handling and the second being nothing.

Don't use `0` as a label and it will work.

For example:

```
Dim WshNetwork As String

On Error GoTo AlreadyMapped:
    Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\server\drive"

AlreadyMapped:
'More code
```

Comment: Sorry I am learning `vba`, are you saying `On Error GoTo 10` is ok? Thank you :).

Comment: @justaguy Try to use descriptive name, like `ErrHandler`